# jQuery - adding class with color attribute to the link

Tags: jquery, css, colors, hyperlink, addclass

Here is my problem. I have a list of dynamically generated classes. Each class has a color. Here is example class:

```
.magenta {
    color: #7abbb8;
}
```

On the other side, I have some links in a footer. I want to use this class when `<p>` in footer is hovered:

```
(function($) {
    $('footer p').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a').addClass('magenta');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This code works perfect - I my a have class="magenta" after p is hovered. But... it doesn't have `color: #7abbb8`. It probably could be easly fixed with `!important`, but as I said, I have a lot of these classes, they are created dynamically, so I don't want to do that. How can I do that another way?

// edit

OK, the problem is somewhere else. I didn't changed classes css, I changed css of every element which had this class. So this color will not be added with class to new elements. Unfortunately there is no simple way to solve this with jQuery, but it seems there are some plugins adding CSS rules to the stylesheet.

Comment: try removing existing class and add which ever class you like to?

Comment: Added CSS as a tag since this is really a css questions since your script works fine.

Comment: What does your css look like? If you imply that it could be easily fixed via using `!important`, which css rules superseed `.magenta`?

Comment: as we all know, id has higher priority than class, why dont u add id instead of class?

Comment: Why not in-line style ` $(this).find('a').css({ color: "#7abbb8" }).addClass('magenta');`?

Comment: Because colors in these classes are not static. I also don't use id, because these classes are used in many places.

Answer (score 1):

Check your style sheet for `a:visited` style Or try to give this style in your css.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do - but I have to do that from jQuery. The question is - how to do that?

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you put in your CSS :

footer p a.magenta, footer p a.magenta:visited, footer p a.magenta:focus, footer p a.magenta:hover  {
color: #7abbb8;}

Comment: One more time: this color is dynamic.

Comment: And what do you mean by dynamic, are you using LESS or some other CSS scripting thingy ?

Comment: I use JS to change color off class (user may change it with a color picker).

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific with your CSS:

```
footer p a.magenta {
    color: #7abbb8;
}
```

or you could always set the color directly :

```
(function($) {
    $('footer p').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a').css('color', '#7abbb8');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and make sure you target the right element, and that would be the element that actually contains the text you are trying to change.

Comment: I can't do that. This color isn't fixed. That's why I use classes. They are also generated with JS.

Comment: Did you try increasing your CSS specificity, as that would probably fix it if you are specific enough and have the styles in the right order, it's all about order and [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)!

Comment: Yes, I know, and default a:link, a:visited etc. is more specific than a {color: x}. So look at the answer to @Vins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035379/jquery-adding-class-with-color-attribute-to-the-link#comment16065202_12035489

Comment: Well, yes it is, but again you are missing the point of specificity, all you have to do is be more specific then you where when setting the `a:visited` styles, and there is no `:visited` selector in jQuery either so that's not going to work, see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ataDU/2/) for specificity!